SpringBoot 3.3.4 app, Hikari, MySQL and gradlew nativeCompile
I have a simple SpringBoot 3.3.4 app - Java v17, Gradle v8.10, I am trying a basic task, open a connection pool using Hikari, running a couple of SQL selects against a MySQL database. I am able to compile using:
./gradlew nativeCompile
Running it on a Apple Mac with M3 "arm64 chip"
I have uploaded the Java code - SpringBoot project on my website:
https://jesusbianco.com/stackoverflow/Test1-Native-Data-MySQL.zip
The code compile - native code without issues:
https://jesusbianco.com/stackoverflow/compile.txt
The errors at runtime is available from the following link:
https://jesusbianco.com/stackoverflow/errors.txt
The code doesn't run properly, it crashes at boot time, some classes cannot be loaded/found, I guess because of the Java's reflection ?
if the build.gradle file is modified at the end of the file, enabling these lines:
jar {
    archiveClassifier=''
    enabled = false
    duplicatesStrategy(DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE)
}

then build with Gradle and run the app:
gradle clean build

java -jar build/libs/test1-native-data-mysql-3.0.jar

It works fine using JVM.
The current issue is running the native image "binary code" without using JVM. I have another project, way more simpler where I can run native code but this one using Hikari and MySQL JDBC driver, is broken :-(

Graal relies on reachability metadata provided by https://github.com/oracle/graalvm-reachability-metadata in order to support reflection. In this case, it appears that the matadata is incomplete. Specifically, the config.addDataSourceProperty("cachePrepStmts", "true"); call triggers a code path that fails.
If you comment out those lines, your application passes.
I've opened https://github.com/oracle/graalvm-reachability-metadata/issues/549 to see if the team at Oracle can fix the metadata. That issue also has a workaround that you can use in the meantime.
